# fdescribe not turning off

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I was focusing on a specific set of tests in Angular 5, so I used fdescribe while I was working on the tests. When I was done, I wanted to verify the rest of the tests were still running before checking in my code. I changed 'fdescribe' back to just 'describe' and restarted ng test, but karma is still only running the tests that were in fdescribe. I haven't found a reason why this might be or how to resolve. Any ideas?

Comment: Just search for a fdescribe or fit in your src folder. And if you find any thing with fdescribe or fit just remove it. And try to run the ng test command again. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've already done that. I only had the one file where I had turned it on, and I removed it from that one file. Here's where it gets weirder - I checked in my file, and on the build system, it is also only running that small set of tests even though fdescribe is no longer set.

Comment: Also look for any use of 'fit' instead of 'it' - both the set of tests (using fdescribe) and individual tests (using fit) can be "focused".

Comment: I check for 'fit' as well. The solution was found by a co-worker of mine. A test needed fixture.detectChanges() added to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how helpful this will be as there were no error messages to indicate what the problem was, but a co-worker and I went back through the test file gradually adding back the tests one by one until we found the one that broke. By adding fixture.detectChanges() to that one test, the problem went away.
EDIT: There was also an expect on an element of toBeUndefined() but the element was really null, so that also needed to be changed to expect toBeNull() instead.